# Show page excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I've one page (mother page) where display child pages, but i can't display the excerpts from child page, the structure is:

- Title
- Thumbnail
- Excerpt
- Read More (link to page)

My code is:

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=asc&parent='.$post->ID);
foreach($pages as $page) {
?>
<div class="block-left" id="<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>">
    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h3>
    <?php echo $page->post_excerpt ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But `<?php echo $page->post_excerpt ?>` Not work :(

Any idea? In advance, thanks :)

Comment: Is `post_excerpt` a object variable or an object function?

Comment: In this case, you should take it as a function, but still does not work properly, then it is a variable